# many to many relationship in oracle analytics

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, oracle-analytics

I'm using Oracle Analytics v5.9 , I have a datawarehouse including a bridge table for implementing a hierarchical dimension. I cannot find a way to join this table with my fact table and my dimension table. i even created a view joining bridge table with Dim table but still no luck.
does this version even support what i'm trying to do..?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-table dataset and Join many to many is available in 6.0.

You can find a video on the YouTube Analytics channel:

https://youtu.be/AaMR80PXl18

You can find also more information on features here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/analytics-cloud/acswn/index.html#ACSWN-GUID-CFF90F44-BCEB-49EE-B40B-8D040F02D476

Hopefully this is helping you.

Ben

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.